# want to keep value to one state of toggle button based on some condition check

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i have a condition where i have to keep toggle button to "off", if my collection object is empty,
now earlier, i was using v-model to update value of toggle button.
but now i am trying :value and input event but i am not able to keep it as off some how it changes value and make it self on.

below i have function which gets called on change event and i am trying to set values.

this is custom component created

```
<toggle-input class="library__action--desktop" :value="lib.enabled" @change="activeInactiveCheck(lib)" />
```

in above html lib is coming from for loop

```
activeInactiveCheck(library) {
      if(library.collection_count > 0) {
        this.$emit('input', event.target.value); // when success i want value to be what user wants
        //some api call to update
      }
      else {
        this.$notify({
          type: "error",
          title: "Please add some Content to your Library if you want to make it active."
        });
        this.$emit('input', event.target.value = false ); // here i am setting it to false so that it can be false
      }
    },
```

i am new in vue and not able to caught my mistake can any one guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<toggle-input class="library__action--desktop" :value="lib" @change="activeInactiveCheck(lib)" />
```

Keep this line like above and set the value of "lib" from view controller where you want to keep it on/off on the given condition.

You can also set it to true/false on controller initialisation.

Also, you don't need to do this

```
this.$emit('input', event.target.value = false );
```

Instead, you can just set "lib" to true/false.